# How to retrieve data from MVC Partial View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, partial-views

I failed to retrieve data from mvc partial view. Just below is the partial view:

**_myPartialView.cshtml**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "_Header";

    var viewDataProduct = Session["ProductDetails"] as Data.DataAccess.Product;

}

<header>
   <div style="top:25px;left:200px; background-color:#2d2d2d; color:#fff;font-size:20px;padding:5px;">
    Product: <span>viewDataProduct.Name</span>
</div>
</header>
```

Below is the view that uses above partial view. I want to retrieve **viewDataProduct.Details** in the View below (ProductView.cshtml).

**ProductView.cshtml**

```
<body>    
    @Html.Partial("_myPartialView")
    <div id="parentDiv">
       <div id="childDiv">
          Product Details: <span> viewDataProduct.Details </span>
       </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Assuming `viewDataProduct` contains data, then its `<span>@viewDataProduct.Name</span>` inside the partial view. But it wont work in the main view unless you also declare `viewDataProduct` (but why do you want to repeat it twice?)

Comment: @{Html.RenderPartial("_myPartialView");} and add @viewDataProduct.Details

Comment: @StephenMuecke
Thanks for response !! Why do I want to repeat it twice ?? It is because each view that use _myPartialView need to retrieve different property from  teh Session["ProductDetails"]  (i.e. var viewDataProduct).

Answer (score 0):

Add the same block to your parent view, you're not retrieving data from the view, you're retrieving it from the session.

```
@{
    var viewDataProduct = Session["ProductDetails"] as Data.DataAccess.Product;
}
<body>    
    @Html.Partial("_myPartialView")
    <div id="parentDiv">
       <div id="childDiv">
          Product Details: <span> @viewDataProduct.Details </span>
       </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

As Stephone Muecke mentioned though you probably don't want to be doing this twice.  I'd recommend reworking your partial to take a model and then passing that model from the parent on down to the partial, probably wouldn't be storing that in the session either but there may be other design constraints influencing your decision to do this.

Comment: Thanks for response !! True- I can't change the existing design that I have to use the session variable (i.e. Session["ProductDetails"] as Data.DataAccess.Product) in _myPartialView.cshtml. Is there any other way that I can access _myPartialView.cshtml data in ProductView.cshtml, like accessing Master Page's data from content page ?

Answer (score 0):

Since your data is in session, you can get the ProductDetails in ProductView.cshtml too and pass the value to partial view.

```
 @Html.Partial("_myPartialView",@viewDataProduct) // replace in main view

// partial view
@model Data.DataAccess.Product

@{
   ViewBag.Title = "_Header";
 }

<header>
   <div style="top:25px;left:200px; background-color:#2d2d2d; color:#fff;font-size:20px;padding:5px;">
    Product: <span>@Model.Name</span>
</div>
</header>
```

Comment: Thank for response !! 

I tried as per you suggested. No Success yet. the _myPartialView.cshtml is used by 12 other views. My goal is to avoid repeating the same piece of code (i.e.  var viewDataProduct = Session["ProductDetails"] as Data.DataAccess.Product; ) in 12 other views that use _myPartialView.cshtml . Instead, I want to declare/get assigned  viewDataProduct in _myPartialView.cshtml and access it from other 12 views.